# How to substring based on a specific characters through iteration?

Tags: iteration, substring, apache-stringutils

I have this following string

```
String oldStr = ".abc.def.ghi.klm.";
```

How do I retrieve the substring and put into another string using a loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < oldStr.length(); ++i) {
   String newStr = doSomethingMethod("oldStr");
}
```

where oldStr should be "abc", "def", "ghi", "klm" recursively

I tried to use StringUtils.subStringBetween(oldStr, ".", ".") but that only handle the first substring.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what results your looking for but i would just use the Split method with the period and get a string array. now each element is a new string.

```
var results = oldstring.Split('.');
```

this gives you an array... "abc", "def", "ghi" ...

if you simply want to remove the periods then you can just use the Replace method

```
var newstring = oldstring.Replace(".","");
```

now you have a string "abcdefghjklm"

Comment: Thanks, using Split method does what I need.

Comment: great.  can you click the up arrow and mark your question as Answered?